# How can I get a Wi-Fi network support after he cut the connection. can not connect to the network again until restar I have kubuntu 14,04

Tags: networking, wireless, kubuntu, network-manager

How can I get a Wi-Fi network support after he cut the connection. Because when it starts laptop it normal after 3 or 4 minutes to work the network connection stays stopped for a few minutes and then cut off communication and can not connect to the network again until restar I have kubuntu 14,04  and the laptop is Lenovo. I hope there is solution.

Answer (score 0):

run  `rfkill list`  before the WiFi disconnects and after the disconnection.
Let me know what is the output.

Drivers for the WiFi chipsets that Lenovo uses are buggy.